# Creating new dataframe with a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a CSV-file with data about all the football matches of the Premier League in the season 17/18. I want to write a loop that splits this data up in tests- and train-datasets. The first test dataset will include all the data from the first 10 match rounds. The next test dataset will include all the data from the first 11 match rounds etc etc. Basically, the test datasets will grow every match round with the matches of the last match round. There are a total of 38 match rounds.

The CSV-file looks like this:[image]

I have written the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

def build_temp_model(dataset, match_round):
   test_dataset = dataset[dataset['Round'] <= match_round]
   if len(test_dataset) == 0:
      return 0
   file_name = str(match_round) + '.csv'
   train_dataset.to_csv(file_name, index=None)

EPL = pd.DataFrame()
EPL = pd.read_csv('/Users/HJA/Desktop/Betting/understatV0.01/test.csv')
EPL = EPL.sort_values(by='Round')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_total_score = [build_temp_model(EPL, round) for rounds in range(11, 39, 1)]
```

However, I get an error in the following line:

```
test_dataset = dataset[dataset['Round'] <= match_round]
```

The error says: *TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'*

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Its not accepting the boolean exp `<` , see  just for the test sake as  `test_dataset = dataset[dataset['Round']  == match_round]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juts a typo. [Pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) would have helped.

```
get_total_score = [build_temp_model(EPL, round) for rounds in range(11, 39, 1)]
```

`round()` is a built in function. `rounds` is the variable you are iterating with.

Comment: @HJA24 I also would have hated to have done all this effort to describe a trivial bug... But look at the bright side: this typo and this question will have been worth if they make you re-examine your tooling and adopt an editor/IDE that does code linting and shows you these error right after they are typed. Lately I am happy user of Visual Studio Code for my python development, but there are lots of choices out there to save you from trivial errors